# OpenShift rhc port-forward closed stream IOError ever few hours

Tags: openshift, portforwarding

I am new to OpenShift. I am trying to run elasticsearch and Kibana (ELK Stack) in the OpenShift gears, but the port-forward seems to be failing every few hours with a closed stream IOError. Could this be caused by some sort of timeout on the port-forward term? Is there a way to permanently enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that our OpenShift setup had a mandatory 5 min. timeout on SSH sessions, and it was killing the port-forward. I wrote a tiny python heartbeat timer to call the elasticsearch once per minute, and that fixes the closed stream problem.